# How to copy parent and child data from one database to another while assigning the newly created parent ids in the foreign key column of child tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Suppose,

I have a table `tblClasses` and `tblStudents`

Now each class have multiple student.

```
tblClass

ID Name
1  ClassA
2  ClassB
3  ClassC
```

tblStudents

```
ID  Name  Class_ID
1.  john   1
2.  Mathew 1
3.  Imran  2
4.  Jenny  3
```

now, I have another server having exact same `db` and tables and I am copying data from `server 1` to `server 2` from same tables using the `Select` and `Insert` e.g.

```
insert into server2.dbo.tblClass (Name)
select Name from server1.dbo.tblClass
```

and for `tblStudents`

```
insert into server2.dbo.tblStudents (Name, Class_ID)
select Name, Class_ID from server1.dbo.tblStudents
```

now this is ok but the real problem is that in `server2` after copying the data, how to populate the `tblStudents` fk `Class_ID` with the actual `IDs` of `tblClass` which are generated after inserting the data into `tblStudents` in `server2` since PKs are Identity and autoincremented and cannot change the design.

What to do in this case?

In simple words, when a parent and child data are copied then in the child table the foreign key field needs to be populated with the actual IDs of the parent not the one from where it is copied which would be obviously different.

I am not allowed to change the table design or properties and have to do it using the queries.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way is to create a `ClassId` mapping table on class records insertion and use this mapping table to translate `OldClassId` to `NewClassId` for the new Student table:

```
declare @ClassIds table (OldClassId int, NewClassId int);


merge into newDB.dbo.tblClasses as target
    using
    (
        select
            Id = Id * (-1),
            [Name]  
        from
            oldDB.dbo.tblClasses
    )
    as source on source.Id = target.Id

when not matched by target then
    insert ([Name])
    values (source.[Name])

output source.Id * (-1), inserted.Id      -- ← the trick is here
into @ClassIds (OldClassId, NewClassId); 


insert into newDB.dbo.tblStudents
select
    s.Id,
    s.[Name],
    ClassId = ids.NewClassId
from
    oldDB.dbo.tblStudents s
    inner join @ClassIds ids on ids.OldClassId = s.ClassId;
```

The major trick is that the `MERGE` statement may work with not not only `inserted` and `deleted` columns (as `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` statements do) but with the `source` columns as well.

Comment: let me try this, thanks and would let you know

Comment: guys, this man here, @vadim, is the king. Man, awesome, superb job. I wish I could had a mind like you. It's done. Great job.

Comment: Given that you only have `when not matched`, you can change the `ON` condition to `1=0`. Also what's the `*-1` about, why is that necessary?

Comment: oh 1 problem occurred. It says "The target of a MERGE statement cannot be a remote table, a remote view, or a view over remote tables."

Comment: @Charlieface yes, good point about `1=0` in `ON` condition — that is also an option. The first my `*(-1)` is to make the `Ids` negative so they don't match any target `Ids`, the second my *(-1) is to return the `Ids` to positive.

Comment: So `ON 1=0` avoids that then

Comment: @Charlieface yes, you are absolutely right — avoids.

Comment: @RobbieRobertson about the "The target of a MERGE statement cannot be a remote table" — that's may be a problem. To solve this I would try to insert data into #TempTable on the remote server or create a cursor, interate through the oldClasses and insert them one by one, to get the new Id for the id-maping table.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go that I can think:

The first is to use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblClass ON`. This is not a design change, so you should be able to do it. After that, you can insert your own values in tblClass.ID (although you will need the select list parenthesis):

```
insert tblClass(ID,Name) values (1, 'ClassA')....
```

Alternatively, you could make a query that connects student ids to class *names*, and then use that back to create the respective connections:

```
-- export/save this in temp table
select s.Name,c.Name as className
into #a
from tblStudents s
left join tblClass c on s.Class_ID=c.ID

--now use this to fill db2 tblStudents
insert tblStudents(Name,Class_ID)
    select #a.Name,c.ID
    from 
        #a
        inner join tblClass c on #a.className=c.Name
```

Comment: for 2nd solution, we can have many students with same names.

for 1st solutuion; what if the ids are already present their?

Comment: If class ids are already present, you cannot use the first solution. About your other question, the student names don't matter - you had three johns before, you will have three johns again. But two Class IDs should not share the same name, only that would cause a problem.

Comment: we have classes with same names having different ids, unfortunately :(

Comment: If you have two classes with name "Math", which have ids 1 and 2 in db 1, and ids 8 and 9 in db 2, how do you know the connection?

Comment: thanks @george. you helped and I learned a lot but went with anohter answer. Worked for me. thanks :()

Comment: @Robbie Robertson Good thing your question was solved. Don't feel obligated to thank everyone or apologise for not accepting the answer - we all know how the game rolls here. Have a good time on Stack Overflow :)